# Checking if time falls between two times using moment not working correctly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to check if a time occurs between two times 4:29 PM and 8:59AM using moment.js, however it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
var dropoff_date = new Date(document.getElementById("car-rental-dropoff-date").value);
var dropoff_time_string = document.getElementById("car-rental-dropoff-time").value;
var format = 'h:mm A';
var dropoff_time = moment(dropoff_time_string,format),
ahStart = moment('4:29 PM', format),
ahEnd = moment('8:59 AM', format);

if ((moment(dropoff_time).isBetween(ahStart, ahEnd)) {
    alert ("it works!");
}
```

However it does work if I change 8:59AM to 9:00 PM, it just doesn't work if I go into the AM, can anyone help me fix this?

EDIT 3: I just got it working, but this code seems a little much, I would appreciate it if anyone has a better way of doing this:

```
var dropoff_time_string = document.getElementById("car-rental-dropoff-time").value;
var format = 'h:mm A';
var dropoff_time = moment(dropoff_time_string,format),

closingToday = moment('4:30 PM', format),
closingYesterday = moment('4:30 PM', format).subtract(1, 'day'),
openingToday = moment('9:00 AM', format),
openingTomorrow = moment('9:00 AM', format).add(1, 'day');

if (((moment(dropoff_time).isBetween(closingYesterday , openingToday)) || (moment(dropoff_time).isBetween(closingToday , openingTomorrow))) {
    //bill = (bill+20000);
    alert ("IT WORKS!" );
}
```

Comment: given that your format does not include a day, it seems to be working fine.  can you incorporate a day so that it knows you mean an overnight period?  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: No, those are just my hours of operation

Comment: Do you have a better way of doing what I need to get done?

Comment: adding a date would be the first thing I would try.  it doesn't know you mean an overnight period.  you are asking it if 4PM comes before 9AM in the same day.  add a date to all three moments and I think it would work.

Comment: No luck James. I will update my code to show work

Comment: you put the same day still, the end time would be the next day

Comment: I changed the ahEnd to 02-01-2001 and still no luck.

Comment: is the dropoff time between 4PM on the first and 9AM on the second?  or does dropoff_day.getday() return 0?

Comment: @JamesSouth - Sorry I think I confused you with my last bit of code, I am going to clean it up. Please check again now.

Comment: @JamesSouth the drop off time was set to 9:21 PM - and thus should have alerted.

Comment: @JamesSouth I understand what you're saying, but 01-01-2001 at 4:40AM would still be on the first, this looks to be a weird quirk of moment.js - if no date is given it should still compute to see if the numbers are in between each other. Right? What is another way to do this that will work?

Comment: i think it's a moment formatting issue, i'm trying to get a codepen going....one thing is that your format is a two digit year but you're using four

Comment: @JamesSouth - I just added more code, check that one out, at least that got some traction but no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment parser is picky I guess. This format works, plus you were missing some `var` declarations on the time variables and missing some semicolons at the end of lines:

```
var format = "MM-DD-YY hh:mm A";
var dropoff_time = moment("01-01-01 8:21 pm", format);
var ahStart = moment('01-01-01 4:30 pm', format);
var ahEnd = moment('01-02-01 8:30 am', format);

if (dropoff_time.isBetween(ahStart, ahEnd)) {
    console.log("it works!");
}
```